# What are the two pipes coming out of the back of my outside air conditioner?

Tags: hvac

On the back of my air conditioner there are two pipes: One is covered with insulation and one is bare pipe.  What is the purpose of these pipes?

Comment: Soft copper tubing. ;)

Answer (score 3):

**A/C Refrigerant Line Set**

Those are the refrigerant lines (what I would call [Freon](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Freon) lines) that feed the *condenser* (the thing outside; half of a split system. The other half is the *coil* inside your furnace's plenum chamber).

The big one (cold) is the suction line. The small one is the liquid line (hot; no need for insulation). Both of these lines run all the way back to your coil.

[Picture](http://www.central-air-conditioner-and-refrigeration.com/home_air_conditioner_maintenance.html)

Comment: "***Refrigerant lines***", not "***freon lines***". Freon is a DuPont trade name for a line of halocarbon products.

Comment: Sometimes I forget that it's not an element.